# Assign integer values to movie clips in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, variable-assignment, movieclip

I am trying to make a card game in Flash using ActionScript 3. I'm not too familiar with the language(grew up with AS2) but I considered it to be more appropriate for this project.

Bad thing about this, though, is that I ran into a problem right away: I'm treating each individual card as a movieclip, but something that I really need is to assign some integer values to the card(It's not really the case, but as an example let's say that I am working on a Poker and I want all Aces to carry the value 1 because they are the best card, 2 for the kings, etc).

I tried looking for it but all I found is how to make arrays of movieclips. I know that this question shouldn't be too hard! Can somebody help me?

(As an aside note, should I really work with movie clips or would buttons be more convenient?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, from my point of view, never use components unless you really need to since they take longer time to draw and they're not flexible. I've had so many issues with them in the past ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677547/actionscript-3-uiscrollbar-bug-width-of-container-returns-85px) I posted being one of those).

About MovieClip's… The MovieClip class is **dynamic** so you can assign any virtual property to it, no problem. So `yourMcInstance.someVar = 3` is perfectly valid.

One of the major changes in AS3, I think, was the introduction of **Sprite** class, which is basically a MovieClip without a timeline. It is much lighter and unless you're manually creating frame animations it is the class to choose for any container that can handle mouse (and many other) events. However, it is not a dynamic class so `yourSpriteInstance.someVar = 3` wouldn't be valid. And that's why using custom classes is encouraged. With custom classes you have the option to extend a class and create custom properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is really helpful. Will have that in mind. And wow, I wouldn't imagine that it was THAT simple. Guess that's why I can't find this elsewhere. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

because Movieclips are Objects, you can actually attach variables directly to them.

```
var card:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); //create a blank MC
addchild(card);

card.id = 5; //You can attach vars like this
```

Comment: That's actually because the MovieClip class is dynamic, not because it's an object. In fact any class in AS3.0 except a few (such as scalars) extends the base Object class.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be a bit harder but yeah, looks like AS3 is flexible like that

Answer (score 0):

To add MovieClips to an Array:

```
const clips:Array = [];

function addNewCardToCardsArray(array:Array, color:String, value:int):MovieClip {
  const clip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  clip.color = color;
  clip.value = value;

  return array[array.length] = clip;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. thanks but really I mentioned arrays because I found all sorts of answers to that question and none to mine, which was a bit frustrating. I'll surely use a similar piece of code for the deck, though!